# no_data_found exception in oracle pl/sql while using collection

Tags: oracle, collections, plsql

```
DECLARE
   TYPE EmpList IS TABLE OF varchar2(50) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

   temp    SYS_REFCURSOR;
   v_temp  varchar2(50);
   v_emp   EmpList;
BEGIN
   v_emp (1) := 'gaurav';
   v_emp (2) := 'manu';

   open temp for select v_emp(level) from dual connect by level<=2;
   loop
    fetch temp into v_temp;
     exit when temp%notfound;
       DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (v_temp);
    end loop;
   close temp;

--the below part works, then why not the above part dint works
 for i in v_emp.first..v_emp.last
  loop
      dbms_output.put_line(v_emp(i));
  end loop;

EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (SQLERRM);
END;
```

Can anyone please tell me why this collection dint work here??,It is giving me no_data_found exception.

Comment: where did you declare `v_temp`?

Comment: @rs: Sorry it was a typo mistake,corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the reason for failure is that

```
v_emp(level)
```

is evaluated (as its a variable) at runtime so would actually evaluate on all rows to
`v_emp(0);`

you could see this if you changed your array to

```
v_emp (0) := 'gaurav';
v_emp (1) := 'manu';
```

the proper way (in case you were not aware) is:

```
create TYPE EmpList IS TABLE OF varchar2(50);
/
```

and then :

```
v_emp := EmpList('gaurav', 'manu');
open temp for select column_value from table(v_emp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
DECLARE
   TYPE EmpList IS TABLE OF varchar2(50) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

   temp    SYS_REFCURSOR;
   v_temp  varchar2(50);
   v_emp   EmpList;
BEGIN
   v_emp (0) := 'gaurav';
   v_emp (1) := 'manu';

   open temp for select v_emp(level) from dual connect by level<=2;
   loop
    fetch temp into v_temp;
        exit when temp%notfound;
       DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('v_temp' || v_temp);
    end loop;
   close temp;

--the below part works, then why not the above part dint works
 for i in v_emp.first..v_emp.last
  loop
      dbms_output.put_line(v_emp(i));
  end loop;

EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (SQLERRM);
END;
```